# Bremsstrahlung radiations

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why are Bremsstralung radiations ignored in case of heavy ions(such as $\alpha$ particles) and not for $\beta$ particles when calculating the rate of energy loss of the heavy ions moving in some medium. (Bethe formula)

Comment: Have a look at the last part of the **total radiated power** section of this article. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power radiated from charged particles is proportional to the square of their acceleration. If equally charged particles are subject to the same accelerating electromagnetic forces then particles with greater mass (i.e. the ions) will experience a much smaller acceleration and therefore emit much, much less power.